# Blueprism Excel VBO issue

Tags: blueprism

When i try to use Excel VBO-open workbook in blue-prism,it says:Internal :Unable to execute code link because the code link throws an exception:The target of the call has an exception.

Then I tried MS Word VBO to read a newly created doc file, but the same problem.

My step is create instance, open workbook .

This xlsx file can be load in other software like uipath.

Answer (score 1):

Probably Blue Prism use comma separator style based on installation location even if windows default language is english.

For me installing [MS Office Language Accessory Pack for Office](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/language-accessory-pack-for-office-82ee1236-0f9a-45ee-9c72-05b026ee809f)(with my native Polish) helps. It changed the comma separator from ' . ' to ' , '

Check also Control panel(Win 7)/Clock, language and Region/Change location/Formats/Additional settings/Decimal symbols

Comment: That’s it!  I tried to change BP language to English, then it works!

Answer (score -1):

More information is required, as the internal exception that you're getting could be caused by ANY number of issues, brought on by either user, Blue Prism, Excel, or the resource/environment.

This has more to do with the poor construction of the Blue Prism Excel VBO than anything.

One piece of advice though: don't use the 'Create Instance' action, ever. Try simply using the 'Open Workbook' action by itself, as if there is not current instance open or identified it will create one anyway and pass out the Instance Handle for use.